# Where should I best spend my time on the 10k tools?

Tags: discussion, review, flags, 10k-tools

Having recently got access to these tools, I've been furiously flagging (mostly NAA and a disturbingly high frequency of "I don't have enough rep to comment so I'm posting an answer", but I'm digressing). Anyway, it seems that the more flags I raise, the more flags I get available next day. So I just try to use them all up, but it takes a lot of time (I was allowed 100 this morning) and it means that I'm not:

1. Answering questions
2. Looking at the delete/undelete queues
3. Looking at the other review queues
4. Doing my day job
5. Paying attention to my wife ....

... you get the picture.

So, given that I like to be involved on this site and given that I have some more tools to do things than I did previously, where is my limited time and effort best spent?

So, what saves the real moderators more time, and/or what improves the site most? I'd hate to think I'm not being effective.

Comment: Options 4 and 5 are *waaay* overrated.

Comment: @Duncan Shhhhhh ... she's *behind* me .....

Comment: Worse than being overrated, they're not effective at all for improving the site.

Comment: Are you going through the flag queues and just re-flagging already flagged questions?  If so, you're not actually resolving any issues (they'll still need moderator attention with or without you re-flagging) so you're not really helping very much.  If you're flagging questions that weren't previously flagged then you're certainly helping, but adding new items to the queue obviously isn't going to make it smaller.

Comment: @Servy Wow, I thought I was somehow helping by doing that... Hmmm!

Comment: @Duncan If you're flagging as invalid for flags that are invalid then you're helping, because it means a mod doesn't need to spend their time looking at it.  If you're just re-flagging it doesn't delete the post, a mod still needs to look at it, and it doesn't really take them less time to resolve the flag just because 2 people think it's NAA instead of 1.

Comment: @Servy Wow too! So would you recommend a different queue or rather that I concentrate on disputing flags instead of adding my tick to the obvious ones?

Comment: @Servy The [privileges page](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/moderator-tools) is a little bit more positive about the idea of re-flagging (*This post is already in the moderators' flag list, but adding your flag will bring the flag up.*), but your point is sound. I had assumed moderators zoned in on high-flagged questions (and I was foolish enough to think 10k flags were special somehow).

Comment: @RogerRowland There's not point in doing anything on the obvious ones.  if it's obvious to you, it'll be obvious to the mod.  You're helping if you're spending your time on non-obvious flags.  If you can point out something that a mod might not catch when looking at it, and can clarify a possibly unclear flag, then you're saving them time.  That said, I personally don't use the flag queue at all, because there are just so few instances in which I can actually *resolve* a flag.  Almost all of what was in the 10k tools that a non-mod could really help with has been moved to /review.

Comment: @Duncan Yes, adding your flag is bumping stuff to the top of the queue.  If you just go around reflagging most everything, you haven't really done much of anything.  And moving stuff up to the top of the queue doesn't really make getting through that queue much easier, in most cases, or at least, it's a much less effective use of your time than going somewhere else where you can actually *resolve* some issues.

Comment: @Servy Thanks. These are two useful comments, I think you should compose them into an answer because it's going to help guide a lot of 10k noobs.

Comment: Servy makes good points about the limited utility of piling on the same flags on already-flagged content. Personally, I don't use the number of flags on something as much of an indicator for me to act on it. We've had viable answers rack up 20+ "not an answer" flags due to indiscriminate flagging. My favorite flags are "other" ones that clearly lay out what's wrong with a post and what we should do about it, because I can make a quick call on those. Bill expands on that below.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

First, thank you for taking time out to help improve the site. The reason I keep volunteering to moderate Stack Overflow is because I see so many other people who care enough to spend their time helping to keep total chaos at bay. Your help is appreciated.

> So, what saves the real moderators more time, and/or what improves the site most?

1. Anything at all that you can do yourself without involving a diamond moderator.  We get a *lot* of flags that don't really require our attention. If it's an active question that you can just vote on, we don't really need to look at it yet. Use all of the other tools at your disposal (votes, editing, etc.) before flagging.  (Unless it's offensive, spam, or hate speech. Flag that immediately. It goes to the top of the flag queue and we handle it as soon as we see it.)
2. Provide as much information as we need to make a quick decision when you do flag something. Tell us what action we need to take (if you know). A few examples:

   - Link only answer - Tell us if the link is broken, redundant, should be a comment, or just useless.
   - "I don't have enough rep to comment so I'm posting an answer" - Can I just delete it, or should I convert it to a comment? Did you edit the preamble out first so it makes sense as a comment?
   - Answer by the OP that should have been an edit to the question - Did you edit the question so I can just delete the "answer" or do I need to do that?

Comment: Brilliant. Useful stuff, thanks. Especially point 2, only one of which I've been doing (editing stuff back into questions). I've also been commenting answers to guide new users - having shortcut comments to enter against "link only" or "comment instead of answer" would make that faster. Is there such a thing?

Comment: @RogerRowland Yes, there's an app for that! Check out the [AutoReviewComments - Pro-forma comments for SE](http://stackapps.com/q/2116) browser plugin.

Comment: Cool beanz! I never knew about this wonderful tool before ... off to explore .... thanks again.

Comment: Is there any likelihood of this being built into the tools? At the moment people flagging "Not an answer" using the built-in dialog in the 10k-tools don't even get to specify which of the sub-reasons it is, compared to those you get in "vote to delete" in the review queue.

Comment: @GaneshSittampalam I don't know of any plans to build this into the tools.